# Appending multiple images after line items in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my data:

```
<ol>
    <li class="us">apple pie</li>
    <li class="ca">maple syrup</li>
    <li class="us ca">cheeseburger</li>
</ol>
```

I want is to have apple pie followed by a tiny American flag (which I have), maple syrup followed by a tiny Canadian flag, and cheeseburger followed by the American flag and then the Canadian flag.

How can I do this with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, but it can only support up to 2 flags.

```css
ol li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ol li[class]::before,
ol li[class]::after {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  order: -1;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.us::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/197/197484.svg);
}

.ca::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/197/197430.svg);
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="us">apple pie</li>
    <li class="ca">maple syrup</li>
    <li class="us ca">cheeseburger</li>
</ol>
```

If you're willing to add more than 2 flags, it's better to do it like this:

```
<ol>
    <li><i class="us"></i>apple pie</li>
    <li><i class="ca"></i>maple syrup</li>
    <li><i class="us"></i><i class="ca"></i>cheeseburger</li>
    <li><i class="us"></i><i class="ca"></i><i class="uk"></i>pizza</li>
</ol>
```

```css
ol li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

i.us {
  background-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/197/197484.svg);
}

i.ca {
  background-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/197/197430.svg);
}

i.uk {
  background-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/197/197374.svg);
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><i class="us"></i>apple pie</li>
    <li><i class="ca"></i>maple syrup</li>
    <li><i class="us"></i><i class="ca"></i>cheeseburger</li>
    <li><i class="us"></i><i class="ca"></i><i class="uk"></i>pizza</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks @hao-wu! Your second solution does what I wanted (add n flags after the terms if they belong to n countries.)

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be that much of a pain if you know about `::after` *pseudo element*-

```
li::after {
  content: url('...');   //add path to the img
  //you can also add other properties to pseudo elements just like others elements
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Docs- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

**Edit 1-**

Now another thing as you require is to use *multiple* images in the third list item. Well that is not possible with `content` property, but you can, in this case, use `background` property-

```
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: url('...img1') url('...img2');
}
```

To place the images apart, you can further specify background positions-

```
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: url('...img1') left center url('...img2') right center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That does put a _single_ flag at the end, but for cheeseburger, it only puts a Canadian flag.. (In general, it seems to only put the _last_ class after the item.. I want it to append _both_ the US flag and the Canadian flag...